# Consulta SQL com SUM e Condição

Tags: sql, sum

Estou com problema em gerar uma consulta que some 6 colunas de quantidade de um produto e retorne apenas 1 vez.
Meu sistema tem 18 filiais, preciso que a consulta retorne apenas os produtos onde a soma de todas as filiais seja ZERO e que a data de ultima saída (DTULTSAIDA) Seja hoje -120 dias.

```
 SELECT PCEST.CODFILIAL,
        PCPRODUT.CODPROD, 
        PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO, 
        SUM(PCEST.QTESTGER)+ 
        SUM(PCEST.QTEST)+ 
        SUM(PCEST.QTPEDIDA)+ 
        SUM(PCEST.QTRESERV)+
        SUM(PCEST.QTPENDENTE)+
        SUM(PCEST.QTBLOQUEADA) AS ESTOQUE,
        PCEST.DTULTSAIDA
   FROM PCPRODUT
  INNER JOIN PCEST
   ON PCPRODUT.CODPROD=PCEST.CODPROD
   WHERE CODFORNEC=27  AND PCEST.CODPROD=2414
   GROUP BY PCPRODUT.CODPROD,
   PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO,
   PCEST.CODFILIAL,
   PCEST.QTESTGER,
   PCEST.QTEST,
   PCEST.QTPEDIDA,
   PCEST.QTRESERV,
   PCEST.QTPENDENTE,
   PCEST.QTBLOQUEADA,
   PCEST.DTULTSAIDA;
```

[print do resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNIOJ.png)

Comment: tire as colunas agregadas da declaração do
 GROUP BY PCPRODUT.CODPROD,
   PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO,
   PCEST.CODFILIAL,
   PCEST.DTULTSAIDA;

Comment: Tirei e está dando erro "not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Putz, não faz sentido , tente o "sum" assim  SUM(PCEST.QTESTGER+PCEST.QTEST+PCEST.QTPEDIDA+PCEST.QTRESERV+PCEST.QTPENDENTE+PCEST.QTBLOQUEADA) AS ESTOQUE,

Comment: Qual o SGBD ? tente criar um exemplo no SqlFiddle